# If a function $f$ is not injective, can its inverse function be surjective?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, inverse

Consider a function  $f : A → B$ and assume that its inverse $f^{-1}$ is a function as well. Give an example of $A, B$, and $f$ such that $f$ is not injective but $f^{-1}$ is surjective.

These are the details of the question.

Is it possible? I do not know how to come up with an example of this.

Does anyone have any idea? Thanks!

Comment: A function $f$ has an inverse iff it is bijective iff it is injective and surjective, so there are no $f$s with that property.

Comment: The fact that it says “the inverse is a function as well” suggests you may have an unorthodox definition of $f^{-1}$. What is the definition you have?